# Unable to get params inside ServerSideProps in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a file like `blog-details/[id].tsx`. And I am trying to navigate via:

```
<Link href={`/blog-details/${item._id}.tsx`}>`
```

After the page navigates, I need to fetch the data from db using the `id`, but the issue here is I am unable to access `context.params` from `getServerSideProps`.

```
const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const params = context.params;
  console.log('route params ', params); // This doesn't get logged on page route
}
```

Comment: Hi Kitti! Have you checked my below answer? Let me know please :)

Comment: @yousoumar Its not working. I had to use `useRouter()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
const id = context.query.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you are exporting `getServerSidePros` from `/blog-details/[id].tsx` file:

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const params = context.params;
  console.log('route params ', params);
  return { props: {} };
}
```

Then you don't need to add this `.tsx` at the end of the URL:

```
<Link href={/blog-details/${item._id}>Go To Blog Details</Link>
```

Unless you want to get a `someId.tsx`.